# Sharepoint 2010 Calendar error

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, calendar, view

A **Calendar** view shows the following error:

> "**This page may have been modified. You may need to reload this page to
>   render the calendar view.**"

Events are also not showing on the calendar. But AllItems page works fine.

I have tried to create new Calendar list but the error is still present on the new Calendar view.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Did you modify the calendar (e.g. add column(s), add color to events by using jquery, etc)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was produced because in masterpage layout Calendar was not nested in the following tag: 
`<div id="s4-workspace">`

Answer (score 0):

Is there any custom columns added to the list? Try to create a new view and select one or two columns and see if it this is going to work? Do this happen in any other web applications? Try to use SPD to dissect the view and see if you find anything different?

Comment: I have created new Standart View and added all possible columns to it presentation.  All data are visible. 
Seems like the problem with standart Calendar view.

Comment: try also to check the console (from the Developer Tools - F12) and see if there is an error thrown and that might give you an idea what else could be happening!

Comment: No one error is in the console. But I cannot change month or scope of calendar - click on these buttons does nothing and does not produce any errors.

Comment: were you able to create it that view on a different web application? What browsers are you testing on?

Comment: On the different web application calendar works normal. I had moved master page to this different web app and got the same error message...